# Alter a where clause on a update through a trigger or similar

Tags: mysql

I'm currently building a replication database (for reporting from) for an already existing database and we are wanting to obfuscate/hash certain columns. Both are on AWS RDS platform with the replication set up as a 'read replica' of the source.

One of the issues with using RDS Replication I've found is you cannot specify which columns to ignore (given that RDS read replicas are supposed to be 1:1 this isn't surprising and I fully understand I'm doing something very niche)

The solution to this problem was to set up triggers on updates/inserts to alter these values, like so:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER clients_insert_obfuscate
BEFORE INSERT ON clients
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.access_token = NULL, NEW.user_token_ttl = 0;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

However one of the values we want to alter is a primary key (the PKs on this table are used as coupon code redemption numbers).

Which leads me to my question - is there anyway of altering the where clause in a update before its executed from within mysql? So on the replica databse, instead of matching against the unhashed code its matching against the hashed code?

So far I have this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insert_obfuscate
BEFORE INSERT ON codes
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.code = SHA2(NEW.code, 256);
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_obfuscate
BEFORE UPDATE ON codes
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.code = SHA2(NEW.code, 256);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

So the insert is fine - but the update trigger is only looking at the params to update - not the where clause.

I understand a trigger might not be the right route to take on this but I'm struggling to find anything else.

Is there anyway of doing this or do I need to look at changing the schema? I would prefer not to change the schema on a production DB though.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt this is possible. And even if it were, it hardly seems like a complete solution. Won't you also have problems with `SELECT` queries that go to the replica, they won't find the correct coupon code.

Comment: yea I'm thinking same unfortunately.

The code isn't used a foreign key and we arent querying against the codes themselves - it always get pulled through the order so I'm not worried about that.

Comment: Do you have to use this field as the PK? Can you add an auto-increment PK?

Comment: I didnt originally create the database so I didnt want to be making any changes - however its seeming more and more likely this is the only option.

I'm going to add a auto increment field tomorrow and just go that route I think.

Thank you for your help!